# What is the definition of a “rectified conv feature map” in a convolutional neural network mentioned in the paper of "visual explaination"?

Tags: conv-neural-network, feature-engineering

I have read the answer of the question

> [What is the definition of a “feature map” (aka “activation map”) in a convolutional neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291820/what-is-the-definition-of-a-feature-map-aka-activation-map-in-a-convolutio?newreg=9e68a698ad0843a5b2546fc322e39db7)

But I don't think that it is same as what I want. I also try to search it on google but I was not able to find that exact thing anywhere.

I have come across this word in this paper: 
[**Grad-CAM:Visual Explanations from Deep Networks via Gradient-based Localization**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02391.pdf)
It is used after CNN in forward propogation.
[image: Image of network where it is used]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it just means a feature map produced by relu (rectified linear) units.